# How to add ContextMenuStrip to ToolStripMenuItem

Tags: c#, winforms, binding, contextmenu

I want that when I click on a menu item, display a context menu with items such as "delete", "rename", etc.

How to bind itself a context menu when you right-click on the menu item?

Comment: You could provide a special `ToolStripMenuItem` *edit menu* item, to open dialog to edit certain part of menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first idea jumping in my mind was hook up some `MouseDown` event on the `ToolStripMenuItem` and show the second `ContextMenuStrip` at the mouse position in screen coordinates. But it's not such simple. The problem is doing so will require hooking up the event for **every** items, on that event somehow showing the second `ContextMenuStrip` **will close** the current ContextMenuStrip (even we add some `Closing` event handler and set `e.Cancel = true;`). It's a little tricky here. We could think of the `MouseDown` event of the current `ContextMenuStrip` but in fact this event is hardly fired because all the items lie on top of the `ContextMenuStrip`. That made me think of the deeper stage where we can catch the `WM_RBUTTONDOWN` and run code there. We can customize the `ContextMenuStrip` to catch that message in `WndProc` or we can use a custom `NativeWindow`. I would like to use a `NativeWindow` here. It's time for the code (working perfectly):

```
public class NativeContextMenuStrip : NativeWindow
{
    public class ShowContextMenuEventArgs : EventArgs {
        public ToolStripDropDown ContextMenuToShow {get; set;}
    }
    public delegate void ShowContextMenuEventHandler(ShowContextMenuEventArgs e);
    public event ShowContextMenuEventHandler ShowContextMenu;
    private Color previousItemBackColor;
    public ToolStripItem SourceItem { get; set; }
    bool keepOpen;
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {                       
        base.WndProc(ref m);            
        if (m.Msg == 0x204) {//WM_RBUTTONDOWN
            OnShowContextMenu(new ShowContextMenuEventArgs());
        }
    }
    protected virtual void OnShowContextMenu(ShowContextMenuEventArgs e)
    {
        var handler = ShowContextMenu;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(e);
            if (e.ContextMenuToShow != null)
            {
                ContextMenuStrip toolStrip = (ContextMenuStrip)Control.FromHandle(Handle);
                Point client = toolStrip.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition);
                SourceItem = toolStrip.GetItemAt(client);
                previousItemBackColor = SourceItem.BackColor;
                SourceItem.BackColor = SystemColors.MenuHighlight;                    
                e.ContextMenuToShow.Closed -= restoreItemState;
                e.ContextMenuToShow.Closed += restoreItemState;
                keepOpen = true;
                e.ContextMenuToShow.Show(Control.MousePosition);
                keepOpen = false;
            }
        }                
    }
    protected override void OnHandleChange()
    {
        base.OnHandleChange();
        ContextMenuStrip toolStrip = Control.FromHandle(Handle) as ContextMenuStrip;
        if (toolStrip != null)
        {
            toolStrip.Closing += toolStripClosing;
        }
    }
    private void restoreItemState(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SourceItem.BackColor = previousItemBackColor;
        SourceItem.Owner.Show();
    }
    private void toolStripClosing(object sender, ToolStripDropDownClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = keepOpen;
    }
}
```

**Usage:**: The important event is `ShowContextMenu`, hook up this event and set the `ContextMenuStrip` you want to show. That's all. Here is the detail:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
  public Form1(){
     InitializeComponent();
     //suppose you have a main ContextMenuStrip and a sub ContextMenuStrip
     //try adding some items for both
     ContextMenuStrip = new ContextMenuStrip();
     ContextMenuStrip.Items.Add("Item 1");
     ContextMenuStrip.Items.Add("Item 2");
     //sub ContextMenuStrip
     var subMenu = new ContextMenuStrip();
     subMenu.Items.Add("Delete");
     subMenu.Items.Add("Rename");  
     ContextMenuStrip.HandleCreated += (s,e) => {
       nativeMenu.AssignHandle(ContextMenuStrip.Handle);
       nativeMenu.ShowContextMenu += (ev) => {
          ev.ContextMenuToShow = subMenu;
       };
     };
  }
  NativeContextMenuStrip nativeMenu = new NativeContextMenuStrip();
}
```

To get the item clicking on which shows the sub `ContextMenuStrip`, you can access the `SourceItem` of the `NativeContextMenuStrip`.

[image]