# C# ToolStripMenuItems with two different Events (Left click and right click )

Tags: c#, .net

So I have a question about C# ToolStripMenuItems. What I want to do is add items dynamically, and bind two events to them, one left mouse click(opens file) and second is right mouse click (opens right click menu with items such as delete, open, etc...). I tried some of the solutions but couldn't really figure it out.
I am this far at the moment:
This void gets looped

```
private void addTemplate(string fileName) {
    var entry = new ToolStripMenuItem();
    entry.Text = fileName;
    entry.Click += new EventHandler((sender, e) => openFile( fileName));
    templatesToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(entry);
}
```

This far it works only for opening files. But how can I make it so that it will also add another event to "entry" so it will open up right click menu with other options. Can't do it with .Click event for sure and Designer doesn't give right click options.

Comment: You need to create a ConextMenu and add that to the control. It will provide a right-click menu and you can add click events to the ContextMenu items. I would suggest creating the ContextMenu in the designer, and just assign it to the toolstripitem when you create in via code

Comment: OK, forget what I first said. Looks like `ToolStripMenuItem` does't support context menus like most controls do. Instead I recommend you check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19994722/how-to-add-contextmenustrip-to-toolstripmenuitem)